# Javascript can't retrieve data from my server

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working in eclipse and I'm making a component for Lumira designer in JavaScript. Beforehand I made a function that can write away data to my database (this one worked fine).

Now I'm trying to make a function to fetch this data back from the server. The problem is I try to see my data with an alert or in the console log but everytime I fetch something my alert either doesn't pop up or is empty and the console log is also empty. But when I check my network it always says that everything is fetched and I can see my objects(see picture below).

My question is why can't I see them in my alert or console? You can find my code and an image of the network below

[image: network]

Fetch I tried to use:

```
getButton.on("click", function() {
    fetch('https://xxxxxx/myphpfile.php').then(
        function(response){
            alert(response)
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(jsonData){
            alert(jsonData)
            //handle json data processing here
        });
```

xmlhttprequest I tried before:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(xhr.responseText)
        var resp = xhr.responseText
        arr = JSON.parse(resp);
        alert(arr);
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'https://xxxxxx/myphpfile.php', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Is your page with the JS on the same domain than your server? you could have a CORS problem.

Comment: if the network tab shows result is not empty, there is no CORS problem to me :)

Comment: do you get a JSON parse error in the console?

Comment: As far as I can see I got no CORS problems (tried alot of solutions to avoid them before but none of them worked either), also the 'alert(resp)' is also empty. With some solutions I tried, I do get the JSON parse error but I can't resolve it with any fixes that I have found before.

Comment: Can you try using the interactive debugger?  If you set a breakpoint inside either of the functions, are they getting hit?

Comment: Also - are you sure there isn't an exception being thrown?  You don't seem to be handling errors with a `.catch(err)` at the end of your promise chain.

Comment: @JustinBeckwith If I try to use '.catch' or any other exception handler i will get an empty component in Lumira designer (this program isn't fully released yet and has still some issues to it could be a bug or me doing something horribly wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like using an Ajax call did the job for me

```
var dataOBJECTNAME='';
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://your_webservice/GETALL_OBJECTS',
            data: '',
            success: function (resp) {
                dataOBJECTNAME = resp;

            },
            error: function () {}
        });
```